# List is being saved in the Model without settings it in the setter

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an Android project and having trouble on the getters and setters. the problem is my Model (getter & setter) is being set with a value without me setting it. im getting the data from the server and storing it in the model if the model is null.

here is the snippet of my code:

This is the Code for the IntentService:

```
  public GameLobbyService() {
    super("GameLobbyService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    while (true){
        if (GameLobbyActivity.inGameRoomStatus.equals("")){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                updateLobby();
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                broadcastIntent.setAction(GameLobbyActivity.LobbyUpdater.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
                broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra(RESPONSE_STRING, responseObj);
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my receiver:

```
public class LobbyUpdater extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String PROCESS_RESPONSE = "com.rudethingstosay.updatelobby.PROCESS_RESPONSE";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String responseString = intent.getStringExtra(GameLobbyService.RESPONSE_STRING);
        int counter =0;
        String roomName = "";
        String gameRoomId = "";
        Boolean gameRoomStatus;
        gameLobby.clear();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonResultArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
            for (counter = 0; counter < jsonResultArray.length(); counter++){
                JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject) jsonResultArray.get(counter);
                roomName = (String) jsonobj.get("email");
                gameRoomId = (String) jsonobj.get("gameRoomId");
                gameRoomStatus = (Boolean) jsonobj.get("gameRoomStatus");
                gameLobby.add(roomName + " room");
            }

            if (GameRoom.getCurrentGameLobby() == null) {
                GameRoom.setCurrentGameLobby(gameLobby);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(lvGameViewLobby.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,gameLobby);
                lvGameViewLobby.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.d("TEST", "NO DATA FROM DB, SAVED CHANGES");
            } else {

                Log.d("MODEL", String.valueOf(GameRoom.getCurrentGameLobby())); //Luma
                Log.d("MODELDB", String.valueOf(gameLobby)); //Bago
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The result must be if i get a new item from the server the ModelDB log must be the latest.

example ModelDb: 1 2 3 4
then the Model Log must be: 1 2 3

but what is happening is.
they both got updated.

D/MODEL: [Test 2 room, Test 3 room, Test 4 room, Test 5 room, Test 6 room, Test 7 room]
D/MODELDB: [Test 2 room, Test 3 room, Test 4 room, Test 5 room, Test 6 room, Test 7 room]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If GameRoom has statitc field currentGameLobby - check if you clear it. I think the problem is that you use static fields

Comment: my point is i don't want to clear it. so i made is static. i want to get the data from the getter as its (OLD VALUE) and the gameLobby is the new value then it will be compared.